# Django REST list-only (no details) ViewSet

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, rest

There is a router:

```
router.register('users', UsersViewSet, base_name='users')
```

And a ViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.get_object_list()

    def get_object(self):
        for input in self.get_object_list():
            if input.id == self.kwargs['pk']:
                self.check_object_permissions(self.request, input)
                return input

        raise MyCustomNotFound()
```

When I go to "/rest/users/" it shows users list. When I go go "rest/users/1" - it shows details of some user.

Now I would like to create an /employees read-only resource, which extends User, but only shows list (typing something like "/employees/1" shows Django 404).

Solutions tried:

1) Override `get_object()` and return Http404 - doesn't work it shows REST page with data instead of 404 page.

2) Using something described at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#readonlymodelviewset - `user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})` in the router file - doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone as late to the party as me, whilst Nimnam1's answer does lead you to the correct answer, I think a more full answer is justified as this is a great question.

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import mixins

class MyListOnlyModelViewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    # your attributes
```

And then you can register this as per usual with a only a List as its possible output.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to inherit from `mixins.ListModelMixin` directly in your handler function?